# How to sort array by the value of the arrays inside

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array that's like,

```
var array = [[CustomModel(set:2, name: "Apple"), CustomModel(set:2, name:"Orange")], [CustomModel(set:1, name:"Home"),CustomModel(set:1, name:"Building")]]
```

how do I sort the array to be like

```
var array = [[CustomModel(set:1, name:"Home"),CustomModel(set:1, name:"Building")], [CustomModel(set:2, name: "Apple"), CustomModel(set:2, name:"Orange")]]
```

so that the value of the set that is lower comes before the value of others.

Is this even possible? or is there a better way to do this.

Comment: What should happen if the inner arrays contain different `set` values?

Comment: It will always be the same since I am referencing it from the same database document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a plain sort if `set` is the same for all elements, then we can just pick the first element of the inner array to sort with

```
array.sort(by: {($0.first?.set ?? Int.max) < ($1.first?.set ?? Int.max)})
```

otherwise we need to pick one, like the smallest value

```
array.sort(by: { ($0.map {$0.set}.min() ?? Int.max) < ($1.map {$0.set}.min() ?? Int.max) })
```